# Search text box corrosponding letter name should be ap

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have emp textbox. The textbox contain names.I want to enter some name in text box and corresponding entries should be visible. Please tell me anyone.

Comment: You are going to have to be much more descriptive than that.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [ASP.NET Ajax AutoComplete](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are telling about autocomplete Feature. If Then You can Use AutoComplete Feature in many ways

1. By Using AutoComplete Property of TextBox, Providing A collection object to it
2. By hooking up KeyPress Event, If User Presses "Enter" Button You can do the retrieval

for Eg . `txtemp_KeyPress() { Do Some Retrival Logic }`

[Sample Data Retrival With Autocomplete in c#](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html)

[Sample Tutorial For AutoComplete](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoCompleteTextBox.aspx)

[Documentation For Auto Complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype.aspx)

Hope i helped u in the problem